# save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'team'

Tags: python, django

When I create new team and trying to associate it to my User's Profile, I get this error is showing. I wanted a team that lot of members and only one creator(or admin of the team) and that creator is also member of the group. How can I associate team with User's Profile?

**Models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    steam_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
    steam_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, unique=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', default='profile_images/default_user.png', blank=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    matches = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    kda = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='players', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='teams', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**Views.py**

```
class TeamsCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = TeamCreationForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        self.request.user.profile.team = form.instance
        print(form.instance)
        print(self.request.user.profile.team)
        self.request.user.profile.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 3):

you get this error because you need to save the Team instance first then save the Profile instance 
After `form.instance.creator = self.request.user` call `form.instance.save()`